# Insert a node in a doubly linked list after a given node

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have a function that inserts an integer after a node in a doubly linked list.  It compiles just fine.  However, when I run it with a test case using a doubly linked list called DLL populated by 2 4 6 8 and try calling the function to insert 5 after 4, nothing happens to the linked list, so this is wrong. I just don't know why.

```
void DoublyLinkedList::insertAfter(const DListNode &p, int newobj) {    
  DListNode *newNode = new DListNode(newobj);
  DListNode *node = header.next;
  while(node != &p) {
    node = node->next;
  }
  node = node->next;
  node->next->prev = newNode;   
}
```

Comment: What is "nothing happens"? You need to come up with some test cases of expected behaviour and check that your logic is working against it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the two pointers (next and prev) in all the DListNode involved.

```
void DoublyLinkedList::insertAfter(const DListNode &p, int newobj) {    
    DListNode *newNode = new DListNode(newobj);
    DListNode *node = header.next;
    while(node != &p) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    newNode->next = node->next;
    newNode->prev = node;
    // test to know if the insertion is in the middle or in the end.
    if (node->next != NULL) // insert in the middle.
        node->next->prev = newNode;
    else // insert in the end.
        lastNode = newNode;
    node->next = newNode; 
}
```

For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Inserting_a_node.

Answer (score 2):

```
2---> 4---> 6--->8
^    |^    |^    |
|____||____||____|
```

You allocate a `newnode`

```
  NULL    5--->NULL
   ^      |
   |______|

//Don't know how you are populating a newnodes next and prev but they should be NULL.
```

After your function ends,

```
2---> 4---> 6--->8
^    |     |^    |
|____|     ||____|
           |
   NULL<---5---->NULL
```

Your list is broken.
You have to update all relevant pointers to keep the structure intact.

```
while()
{.. 
} 
newNode->next = node->next;
newNode->prev = node;
node->next=newNode;
if(newNode->next!=NULL)
     newNode->next->prev=newNode;
```